# Blender failing to bake

Tags: baking

I've had this problem for a long time, but now is getting worse.

When Blender is baking, I see that it consumes alot of memory, so I went and bought more RAM to a total of 32GB, thinking it would fix this, but it started happening again.

So, what happens is that, when Blender is baking, it starts consuming memory, getting ready to bake, but alot of times it won't actually bake and just display a black image, but the message at the bottom still displays, saying the bake was a success. This is not because of metallic, it just doesn't even bake. I try to fix this by closing Blender and opening again and creating a image file to bake with a different name, and works most of the time, but it's getting worse.

I'm baking 8K textures, btw.

Comment: hello, maybe share a file so that we can try?

Comment: It's resolved. I had too many objects being rendered. Even though they were invisible, that made no difference, so I disabled them in the camera icon. Now the bakes are super fast and without issues.